# Creating a scatter plot in R with multiple y-axis-values for each x-axis-value?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, charts, scatter-plot

I have the following example dataframe:

`jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec someValue
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   109.24673
0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   108.24444
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   247.25433
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   192.22873`

I now want to create a scatterplot with every month beeing one section on the x-axis. The "someValue"-column shall be the y-axis.
For each "1" in the month-columns it shall create a dot at the appropriate part of the scatterplot. Every "0" should be ignored and not visible in the plot.

How can i accomplish that in R? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your data is called df:

```
df = structure(list(jan = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), feb = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), mar = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), apr = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), may = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), jun = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), jul = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    aug = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), sep = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), oct = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L), nov = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dec = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), someValue = c(109.24673, 108.24444, 247.25433, 192.22873
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

You can do this in base R (good old times):

```
ind = which(df[,1:12]==1,arr.ind=TRUE)

      row col
 [1,]   2   6
 [2,]   2   7
 [3,]   3   7
 [4,]   4   7
 [5,]   1   8
 [6,]   2   8
 [7,]   3   8
 [8,]   4   8
 [9,]   2   9
[10,]   3   9
[11,]   4   9
[12,]   3  10
[13,]   4  10
```

So what you want to plot, is the column number on x and corresponding row value for someValue, and let's put this into a data.frame

```
plotdf = data.frame(x=ind[,"col"],
y=df$someValue[ind[,"row"]])

    x        y
1   6 108.2444
2   7 108.2444
3   7 247.2543
4   7 192.2287
5   8 109.2467
6   8 108.2444
7   8 247.2543
8   8 192.2287
9   9 108.2444
10  9 247.2543
11  9 192.2287
12 10 247.2543
13 10 192.2287
```

You can just use base R (good old times):

```
plot(plotdf,xlim=c(1,12),xaxt="n",ylab="somevalue")
months = colnames(df)[1:12]
axis(1,at=1:12,labels=months)
```

[image]

Or if you like some fancy graphics, we can use plotly, using plotdf and months we defined previously:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(x=plotdf$x,y=plotdf$y,type="scatter") %>% 
layout(xaxis=list(range=c(0,13),tickvals=1:12,
dtick=1,ticktext = months))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that worked for me. I just want to mention that i got confused by your first representation of the dataframe. I already have a very large dataframe with 12 columns for each month and 1 column for the extra value so i could just ignore that first step creating the dataframe. Just to mention for future people reading this.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to bring the data into the right shape, i.e. converting to long format by e.g. `gather` from `tidyr`. Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tribble(
   ~jan, ~feb, ~mar, ~apr, ~may, ~jun, ~jul, ~aug, ~sep, ~oct, ~nov, ~dec, ~someValue,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 109.24673,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 108.24444,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 247.25433,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 192.22873
  )

months <- names(df)[grepl("^\\w{3}$", names(df))]

df_gather <- df %>% 
  gather(month, value, -someValue) %>% 
  mutate(
    # Convert to factor and set order of months
    month = factor(month, levels = months),
    # Set "0" to missing
    someValue = ifelse(value == 0, NA, someValue))

ggplot(df_gather, aes(month, someValue)) +
  geom_point()
#> Warning: Removed 35 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>